# No 'read-more' to specific content type (eg page)

Tags: theming, nodes

I've been making a content type page for my Drupal 7 website. 
I'd like to see an option to disable the 'read more' and the 'link' to the /node/x in the content type customization.
I just want it to be displayed on the home 'as is'.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing the "teaser" mode and tweaking node--your_content_type.tpl file.

To remove the teaser mode: Go to "Structure > Content types > your content type"; 
click on "Manage display"  and "Custom display settings"; uncheck the "Teaser" checkbox.
This will display the content in the front page as is.

[image: screenshot]

Now to remove the "read more" link, unset it in your node--your_content_type.tpl.

```
unset($content['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']);
```

This way you will not have "read more" link in your home and the whole content will be displayed for your content type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module, which allows controlling fields shown in different view modes for a content type.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove links just by using [hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)