# How to remove "READ MORE" in Marinelli theme at  frontpage?

Tags: views, theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No 'read-more' to specific content type (eg page)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25657/no-read-more-to-specific-content-type-eg-page)

Hi i am using Marinelli theme for my website and i need to remove the **READ MORE** option at the front page, i created a front page with **BASIC PAGE**  content using **VIEWS**. What should i do to make it a full page ?